# The PIC24F RETURN instruction

Tags: pic, assembly

The PIC model I have is [PIC24FJ128GA010](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39747F.pdf). My question how many clock cycles does the RETURN instruction consume?  The datasheet says 3(2), what does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some information in the 24F [Programmer's Reference Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70157F.pdf), which is always a good place to go if you need to understand individual assembly language instructions.

On page 48 we find the following table, which is a slightly more useful version than the one in the datasheet:

[image]

On page 11 there is a small hint at the exception processing mechanism:

> 2.1.1.6 EXCEPTION PROCESSING
>
> The 16-bit MCU and DSC devices have a vectored exception scheme with support for up to 8 
>   sources of non-maskable traps and up to 246 interrupt sources. In both families, each interrupt source can be assigned to one of seven priority levels

So it seems if there is a non-masked trap or interrupt waiting it will only take 2 cycles for RETURN to finish and begin to service the relevant code.  If the return is going to "normal" code then it will take 3 cycles.